# How to make define a segments function

Tags: haskell

How to define a function segments which takes a finite list xs as its argument and returns the list of all the segments of xs. (A segment of xs is a selection of adjacent elements of xs .)

For example, segments [1, 2, 3] = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [2, 3], [1], [2], [3]].

I know how to write a inits, but how can I extend to this situation!

```
segments :: [a] -> [[a]]
segments [] = []
segments (x:xs) = [x:xs] ++ segments (init (x:xs))
```

Comment: Why is the empty list not a segment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can write your own `inits_` function (I specially add `_` to the end because `inits` is standard function with a bit different behavior), you can write function `segments` by calling `inits_` for all tails (I just rewrote your code of `segments` and rename it to `inits_`):

```hs
inits_ :: [a] -> [[a]]
inits_ [] = []
inits_ xs = xs : inits_ (init xs)

segments :: [a] -> [[a]]
segments [] = []
segments (x:xs) = inits_ (x:xs) ++ segments xs
```